# Can't retrieve get JSON values with Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I'm doing something wrong, but I can't seem to figure out what it is.

The $.getJSON line should retrieve the data via an AJAX request, passing it the currently selected fruit name. The data is then looped through (it's an array containing the index 'variety' containing the fruit variety name) and added to an html string, which is then finally injected by Jquery into the web page's #varieties span replacing what was previously there.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Toevoegen</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function populateFruitVariety() {

            var fruitName = $('input[name=fruitName]:checked').val();

            $.getJSON('func.php', {fruitName: fruitName}, function(fruit) {

                var html = '';
                $.each(fruit[fruitName], function(index, array) {
                    html = html + '<label><input type="radio" name="variety" value="' + array['variety'] + '" />' + array['variety'] + '</label> ';
                });
                $('#varieties').html(html);

            });

        }



        populateFruitVariety();
        $('input[name=fruitName]').change(function() {
            populateFruitVariety();
        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>

<form>

    <div>
        <strong>Fruit:</strong>
        <label><input type="radio" name="fruitName" value="Apple" checked="checked" />Apple</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="fruitName" value="Banana" />Banana</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="fruitName" value="Orange" />Orange</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="fruitName" value="Pear" />Pear</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <strong>Variety:</strong>
        <span id="varieties"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <strong>Type:</strong>
        <span id="type"></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

**FUNC.PHP**

```
<?php
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";



$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);


$rows = array();
if(isset($_GET['fruitName'])) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT variety FROM fruit WHERE name = ? ORDER BY variety");
    $stmt->execute(array($_GET['fruitName']));
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}

echo json_encode($rows);

?>
```

For some reason, this is not working properly because Jquery won't pick up the json values as I can see from the console.

When changing the last piece of jquery code into:

```
$(function() {
            populateFruitVariety();
            $('input[name=fruitName]').change(function() {
                populateFruitVariety();
            });
        });
```

The values will be retrieved in the console, but not shown as radioboxes. There's still an error in the console though. (a is undefined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unable to test this but if you change -

```
$.each(fruit[fruitName], function(index, array) {
```

to

```
$.each(fruit, function(index, array) {
```

does it work?

Comment: Wooh that seemed to work! BUT, only when using: _$(function()_

According to this tutorial, it should be possible with _fruit[fruitName]_ and without the _$(function()_, see:
http://www.electrictoolbox.com/json-data-jquery-php-radio-buttons/

Answer (score 0):

Note to everyone using these tutorials, they are *old*! and using jQuery 1.4.2 - I just spend more than a day trying to make a simple `selectbox` work (http://www.electrictoolbox.com/json-data-jquery-php-mysql/, `new Option()` doesn't seem to work in 1.7.2), didn't work with jQuery 1.7.2, when I switched to jQuery 1.4.2 it worked rightaway.

In the above example jroen is using jQuery 1.6.1, that might be the issue.